# How to listen to external event continuously in Electron/NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, dom-events, modbus

I have an Electron app, which uses modbus-serial module to read and write to modbus PLC register addresses.
I want a way to continuously monitoring any change to a PLC address. 
If any change is found, update it on application.

I have successfully created internal events, but I have no idea, how my application can check if register address is modified by some external factor.

Any type of guidance/ help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just an opinion. Does PLC address change emit any event? If not then you can use `setInterval` to check if the address has changed and perform necessary actions!

Comment: Checking for address change on interval is the only way?

Comment: I do not have hands on experience with it. I just gave you my opinion. There might be other solution to that.